# Understanding a proof in Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Closed subsets of compact sets are compact
>
> *Proof*: Suppose $F \subset K \subset X$, $F$ is closed (relative to $X$), and $K$ is compact. Let $\{V_{\alpha}\}$ be an open cover of $F$. If $F^c$ is adjoined to $\{V_{\alpha}\}$, we obtain an open cover $\Omega$ of $K$. Since $K$ is compact, there is a finite subcollection $\Phi$ of $\Omega$ which covers $K$, and hence $F$. IF $F^c$ is a member of $\Phi$. we may remove it from $\Phi$ and still retain an open cover of $F$. We have thus shown that a finite sub collection of  $\{V_{\alpha}\}$ covers $F$

So the second step confuses me. Basically they are saying the union of the complment of $F$ and the open cover of $F$ covers $K$. I don't see why this is true. Why can't $F^c \subset K$? If that were true, doesn't it mean it wouldn't necessary cover $K$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\forall x\in K, (\text{and}\;\;\forall x \in X)$: $x\in F\cup F^c$. $\;x\in F$ or $x\in F^c \implies (x \in F$ or $x \notin F$). That is $x$ is in $F$, or it's not in $F$ (Law of excluded middle).   If it's in $F$, it's covered by the open cover of $F$: $\{V_\alpha\}$.  If it's in $F^c$ (i.e., if it's not in $F$), it's covered by $F^c$.

Whatever the case, it's covered: all of $X$ so all of $K$ is covered, and since K is compact, it can be covered by a finite subcover, and following the proof, $F$ can then be covered by a finite collection of $\{V_\alpha\}$, so it too is compact.

---

Edit: Since the problem seems to be in understanding $F^c$, the complement of $F$ relative to $X$:

**Complement clarification**: See image.

Let $X = U = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$.

Let $F = B = \{0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8\}.$

Then $F^c = B'= X \setminus F = U \setminus B = \{2, 3, 9\}$

[image]

Comment: Okay but what if there is another party member in $X$ that is disjoint from all the Fs?

Comment: Then it's in $F^c$.

Comment: Again: any element of $X$, and of $K$ is either in F, or not in F. By the definition of the complement of F in X, an element in the complement of F is not in F: $X\setminus F = F^c;\;F\cup F^c = X$.

Comment: Sorry I meant like why can't $K = F \cup F^c \cup Y$ for $Y$ is some new set such that $Y \cap (F \cup F^c) =\empty$

Comment: The **complement** of a set $F \subset K \subset X$ is made up of ALL elements in set X which are NOT in $F$. We are interested only in $F \subset K \subset X$. If $Y\cap(F\cup F^c) = \varnothing$, then $Y\not\subset X$, so it is of NO relevance in the given proof.

Comment: Sorry I drew a venn diagram of what's happening. Basically I have big $X$ as the universe and I have three circles (sets) all disjoint from each other and all of them are subsets of $X$. I labelled the three sets, $Y$, $F$ and $F^c$.

Comment: You're not understanding: if $Y \cap F = \varnothing$, since $F^c = X \setminus F = X - F$, then $Y\subseteq F^c$. $F^c$ is ALL of X except for F.

Comment: @sizz: In your Venn diagram with the three circles, presumably you have one of the circles labeled as $F$. That means the other two circles are not part of $F$, i.e., they are part of $F^c$. Not just one circle is $F^c$. Remember, every elements either IS in $F$ or IS NOT in $F$. There are no exceptions to this rule inside the universe of $X$. Thus, $X=F\cup F^c$, which is a disjoint union.

Comment: So basically $Y$ gets sucked into $F^c$?

Comment: But how do I know that $F^c \not\subset K$? There is still a possibly that $F^c \subset K$ and $F^c \cap F = \phi$

Comment: We know $F\subseteq K$. Assuming $F\neq\varnothing$, then there is some element in $K$ that is not in $F^c$. Note that $F^c\cap K$ may not be empty, though, since we aren't saying $F=K$.

Comment: Sorry but since $F \subset K$, can $F^c \cap K $ even be empty?

Comment: Sizz, if it's still not making sense, try building an example. Let $X=\mathbb{R}$, $F=\{x|0\leq x\leq 1\}$, and $K=\{y|-1\leq y\leq 2\}$. Ignore the fact that $F$ and $K$ are clearly compact and instead build $F^c$. What is $F^C$ in this case? Does $F\cup F^c$ cover $K$ in this case?

Comment: If $F\subset K$ and $\subset$ indicates a proper subset, ($\exists x\in K$ with $x\notin F$) then no, $F^c\cap K$ cannot be empty.

Comment: @ToddWilcox, in your example. $F^c$ is pretty much $\mathbb{R^2} \backslash F$, so I guess I see what you mean.

Comment: Is this helping, sizz?

Comment: @ToddWilcox, oh okay I didn't notice that subtlety. Thank you. I think I am beginning to see my flaw. Interesting confusion eh?

Comment: Actually, $F^c$ would not be $\mathbb{R}^2$ at all. In my example, $F^c=\{z\in\mathbb{R}|-\infty <z<0,$ or $1<z<\infty\}$.

Comment: No I meant $\mathbb{R}^2$ without the infinite rectangle contained by $F$. I was sturggling to figure out how to type out \ in latex.

Comment: And since we're trying to prove that F is compact (the proof you posted), and already know K is compact, it would be trivially true if F = K, so we can safely assume F is a proper subset of K, which works fine.

Comment: I was taking $X=\mathbb{R}$, not $X=\mathbb{R}^2$. Aside from that, it looks like you're getting it, or at least getting very close. And $F^c$ is exactly $\mathbb{R}\backslash F$. It's just two ways of writing the same thing.

Comment: sizz: I think Todd was using x, y, z just to distinguish elements of the respective sets.

Comment: Maybe I got the idea but just from a wrong example? I thought you made a typo on $X = \mathbb{R}$ in the first place

Comment: Is this making sense now? I do agree that Rudin can be rather brief and dry in his proofs.

Comment: Ooooooo.... $x,y,z$ confused you? Ohhh... Hm. Yeah, I didn't mean the typical usage of $x$, $y$, and $z$ to be the normal coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^3$. My bad. No, just three arbitrary variables in regular old one-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$. Thanks for realizing that, amWhy.

Comment: No I redid the whole thing and I think our "examples" were saying the same thing.  $F^c$ alone doesn't cover all of $K$, but the union of $F^c$ and $F$ here does

Comment: @Todd no worries: I appreciate you helping out.

Comment: Correct!! Actually, the union of $F$ and $F^c$ covers $X$ also.

Comment: Btw, if you try my example (where we took $X = \mathbb{R}^2$, we are saying more or less the same thing I think

Comment: yes, I think you're right...sizz

Comment: @ToddWilcox, are we back in square one again? Ah sigh, I thought the union of $F^c$ and $F$ *IS* $X$. A set can't cover itself right? Or is this also consistent with the fact that there is no darn way I can find a finite subcover of $X$ anyways (since $\mathbb{R^n}$ isn't compact)

Comment: Oh, you are probably right. I'm trying not to panic about the fact that I just looked for my baby Rudin and don't know where it is. $F^c\cup F$ IS $X$, yes. If a set can't cover itself then you are totally right. I think I was playing too fast and loose with "cover" just there and I apologize.

Comment: $F^c \cup F = X$, yes. The cover of K, is finite (since K is given as compact), but also covers F. If we remove the cover of the part of $F^c$ from the cover of K, the finite cover of K then reduces just enough to show that there exists a finite cover of F, hence F is compact. Which was to be shown.

Comment: I have a definition of "cover" by Richardson that allows a set to cover itself, but the cover must be open, so my possibly erroneous statement would work if we use Richardson's definition and $X$ is considered open. But this is all besides the point.

Comment: I am probably pushing this discussion a little too much. But while we are on the topic of whether a set itself can cover, itself, then shouldn't we necessary add to the proof that the complement must cover more than $K$ and not just $K$? But I suppose that's obvious and doesn't need to be stated

Comment: @Todd, aren't all covers, by definition *open*? At least that's how Rudin suggests it. In fact, it's the first definition in the topic of compact sets. It stresses *open cover* and doesn't seem to acknowledge the existence (if it does) of other type of covers.

Comment: Yes, covers are open, but the proof shows that for closed F, we can have a finite open cover of F. I wouldn't worry too much abuot it now, but you'll probably encounter an exercise to find an open cover for the interval [0, 1] in $\mathbb{R}$ sometime soon.

Comment: We shouldn't add anything to a proof that is not necessary for the proof. In this case, I only mentioned the expanse of $F\cup F^c$ to try to clarify what it contains. I don't think we should get too bogged down on whether a set can cover itself, unless you are fully clear on the proof in question and then maybe asking a new question would be a better way to discuss that. I'm pretty sure if a set is open, it can cover itself by most, if not all, definitions.

Comment: But the book Todd uses suggests, according to him that, *but the cover MUST be open* covers don't necessary have to be open?

Comment: For your purposes, since you are using Rudin, all of your covers must be open. Even in my book by Richardson (all I have handy right now), all covers are open. I think we can safely assume that all covers are open. Again, that's not really related to the question and answer we are commenting on so it would be best for Math.SE if we leave it at that or open a new question about whether a set can cover itself.

Comment: Yes, closed sets can/must have open covers, but you'll get to that soon enough. It's not crucial here in this proof.

Comment: Basically the open set serves an open cover, for itself. I think that's what you were getting at? In that case I can tolerate the idea, though I yearn for a stricter condition. I'll accept it for now. Thank you all, I think we 've broken the record for longest comments chain haha, and thank you for participating too! (37 comments wow)

Comment: Already ahead of you (acceptance), I am not sure how much content I can add to follow up on my question. It would be somewhat empty to barge out and ask "okay guys, can open sets serve as an open cover, for itself?"

Comment: Actually I think I can add some content, Rudin's seem to have added a condition which doesn't allow this. I will ask

Comment: The more comments here the more pluses needs here.

Answer (score 1):

Every member of $K$ is either in $F$ or in $F^c$.  If it's in $F$, it's covered by the open cover of $F$.  If it's in $F^c$, it's covered by $F^c$.  So in either case, it's covered.

Comment: What if there is a third set $Y$ that's disjoint from all the $F$s?

Comment: @sizz $F^C$ means the complement of set $F$.  Everything in $X$ that isn't in $F$ is in $F^C$, by definition.  So there is no third case.

Answer (score 1):

$$X\subseteq F\cup F^c$$
Since $F\subseteq\cup\Omega$ (Here $\cup\Omega$ is the union of all elements of $\Omega$), therefore:
$$X\subseteq\cup\Omega\cup F^c$$
Thus:
$$K\subseteq\cup\Omega\cup F^c$$

Answer (score 1):

The open cover you're dealing with is $\{F^c\} \cup \{V_\alpha\}$.  This covers the entire space $X$, not just $K$. To see this, let $x \in X$.  Either $x \in F$ or $x \notin F$.  If $ x \in F$, then

$$x \in F \subseteq \bigcup V_{\alpha}$$

Otherwise, $x \in F^c$, so $X \subseteq F^c \cup \bigcup V_{\alpha}$.